# Open change language in setting in all brand with intent

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I am going to chage system language in my application and need to open setting with intent.
My intetnt code is :
`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS))`
I am going to write test-case for it and using from appium robotest framework i call above function to open setting app i see different page from **Xiaomi poco** divices. Can you help me to solve this solution?

This is my apppium code :
`Open My App   # wait to load tvLangauge complate and click it  Wait Until Element Is Visible    id= tvLanguage Click Element`    
You can see diffrent between Samsung and Xiaomi here :
[image: xiaoni]

[image: samsung]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Those are both the language selection screens of the speciifed OS.

Comment: I checked it with appium with this scenario open setting - open langauge and inpunt - now i elelect a specefic item but in xiaomi device is diffrent .

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I dont think there's a real solution for that,I think you need to have specific code for xiaomi since it's a custom OS

Comment: I have same idea , Thank you!!!